# How do I modify this part of code to avoid 'Too Many SOQL'

Tags: apex, soql, batch

I have the following SOQL inside a For loop in a batch class that checking the SUM of each vendor with specific Expiration Date. vdrWithExpiryDates is a map that store different expiration date for each vendor

```
for (String vdr: vdrWithExpiryDates.keySet()) {
  AggregateResult[] agrEarnings = [
    SELECT SUM(Amount__c)ern
    FROM Rewards_Bank__c
    WHERE Amount__c > 0 AND Vendor__c = :vdr 
    AND Expiration_Date__c <= :vdrWithExpiryDates.get(vdr)];
}
```

Any suggestion on how to modify this so I can avoid 'Too Many SOQL'?

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** that the value of the comparand for `Expiration_Date__c` varies by vendor, which seems to be the case based on your use of a Map to store this data, you can't bulkify this query further *as currently implemented* and it will always fail when you attempt to run it for more than 100 vendors in a single Apex transaction.

If the value to compare with `Expiration_Date__c` were a constant, you could do something like this:

```apex
  AggregateResult[] agrEarnings = [
    SELECT SUM(Amount__c) ern
    FROM Rewards_Bank__c
    WHERE Amount__c > 0 
          AND Vendor__c IN :vdrWithExpiryDates.keySet() 
          AND Expiration_Date__c <= SOME_DATE_VALUE
    GROUP BY Vendor__c
  ];
```

But since you apparently need to apply a different criterion for each `Vendor__c` value, that won't work. Instead, you'd have to either:

(a) limit your code to only ever process 100 or fewer Vendors, or

(b) write asynchronous Apex, such as a [Batch class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm), to process Vendors in batches that are small enough (<=100) to avoid incurring the SOQL limit, or

(c) adjust your data model so that you can express the expiration date limit in some other way. For example, if the per-vendor expiration date is stored on the Vendor object, you might be able to add a formula field on `Rewards_Bank__c` called `Is_Expired__c` with a formula `TODAY() < Vendor__r.Expiration_Date__c`. Then, you can write a query with `GROUP BY` as shown above and simply filter by `Is_Expired__c = false`, avoiding the per-vendor criterion.